# Can a Win8 Metro-JS app take a screenshot of itself?

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-8, microsoft-metro, screenshot

I'd like to use a screenshot of the current state of my game as the panel that helps users figure out which of their save states they're looking at.  I can snap the data and generate it, but that's a lot of hassle, and if there's some way to just say "I'd like a screenshot of myself," that'd save me a huge amount of time.

I have no interest in screenshots of other applications.

Can a Metro JS (or Modern UI, I guess it's called now) application self-screenshot somehow?

Comment: No, it isn't.  That's not a self-screenshot, and that's the wrong language.  The limitation they're citing is that you can't screenshot the entire screen, because it might include the other app.

This is a substantially different question.

Comment: Ok, have removed the original dupe attribution to not dissuade further discussion. Rob calls out that specifically C#/XAML can't do the self-screenshot (but reaffirms no app can do the full screenshot).

Comment: I appreciate your choice.

I should also point out that I don't actually require the platform to do the work.  If there's some crafty way to do it in pure javascript, that seems fine too.

Comment: given it's a game, are you rendering everything on Canvas?  perhaps [toDataUrl] (http://bit.ly/Rc8yz3) would be a start? (comes with caveat that I've not tried it in the context of a Windows Store app)

Comment: I am not currently rendering in <canvas>, no.  Otherwise that'd be exactly the kind of thing I need.

Comment: Would this help? http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/index.html It doesn't take an actual screenshot, but builds data based on the DOM.

Comment: That is ... interesting.  It is mostly getting things right, too.  If I can figure out how to get past the glitchy stuff, maybe that'll save me a lot of time.  Thank you sir.  `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no official way to take a screenshot of yourself. I tried to call into SendKeys locally as a hack to see if you could send the PrintScreen key to the Window and then pull the result off the clipboard. If there would be anyway to do this, it would be that (though I haven't had luck as I mention). To call that from a JS app, you would need to have the code in C# or C++ and then expose it as a Windows Runtime component that is referenced and called by the JS code.

If there was going to be any workaround without duplicating the rendering of data yourself, I'd imagine that would be it.

Comment: That's an interesting position, attempting to load something from another language into context to support.  I'll give that a try; thank you for the idea.

Comment: It's one of the reasons I love WinRT (then again, I'm a bit biased as that is the technology I work on :P). You can do this for several reasons to (it's what I did to build a drum sequencer internally, shell out to C# code for Zip functionality, etc.).

Comment: Yeah, it makes perfect sense; I actually already have an app loading a .DLL that I built from Erlang through Gambit Scheme, because the video game needs mass agent behavior (think Roller Coaster Tycoon,) and it was so much more pleasant in an actor language.  I don't know why I didn't think of this, but pro mode on you for having done so.  `:)`  Cheers.

Comment: Oooo, that sounds awesome! Brilliant :).